# Evento Cancelar Dialog Print

Tags: javascript, html

Se puede capturar el evento de los botones imprimir o cancelar desde un dialog de html...
Estoy haciendo un ejemplo de impresion de un ticket pero al imprimir quiero que se cambie de pagina, en mi ejemplo solo econtre un evento despues de la impresion pero si cancelo de igual forma se va pero lo que quiero es identificar si preciono imprimir o cancelar

Comment: Has intentando algo? Si es así añade parte de código para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138939/how-to-trigger-javascript-on-print-event

Comment: Solo hice este ejemplo pero como mensione anteriormente quiero capturar el evento del boton despues que imprima para cambiar de pagina